# UTM Parameters showing as different pages

Tags: google-analytics

We have UTM parameters set up for all our campaigns. We also have automatic reports using regex set up to filter out the right pages - but the UTM parameters are causing an issue.

The example below shows that when you look at the campaign on GA and do a secondary dimension of Page, there are two different listings - one with #utm_source and one without.

[UTM Parameters showing as different pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfKZQ.png)

Why is this happening? Ideally we just want this to show as one entry WITHOUT the UTM and then I can always find the UTM information if I look at a secondary dimension or source/medium etc.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `#` that should be `?`

So you have to check if you have generated a wrong querystring in campaign URL or if there is somenthing in your website that append the querystring also as fragment.

Comment: Ahh yes! I will look into the source of this but to solve this retrospectively, could I just use the Google Analytics search-and-replace filter to search for #utm_source and replace to ?utm_source

Would that work retrospectively?

Comment: Historical data cannot be changed.